# Django nested transacion.atomic() questions. Is it significant what exception is raised to abort a transaction?

Tags: django, database, postgresql

I'm writing code which is basically to upload a spreadsheet. Each row requires the creation of multiple DB objects and relationships. If the data in the row is incapable of being stored, I want to tell the user about the problem, abort the transction representing this row, and continue with the next row. But if there's a more disastrous failure or "too many errors", I want to abort the outer transaction to commit nothing at all to the DB.

Is there any particular recommended Python or Django exception class to subclass, to generate exceptions for this purpose?

And can I safely catch IntegrityError in the row-processing code so as to issue the best possible error to the user, and then exit the inner transaction by railsing a different exception?

I'm thinking `Class CannotStoreRow( ValueError): pass`, because something in that row of data is an invalid value. Is there any reason something other than `ValueError` should be used? (Why doesn't Django supply something like `AbortTransaction`, or does it? )

Overall outline code:

```
try:
    with transaction.atomic():
        process_spreadsheet()
except CannotContinueLikeThis:
    # tell user we have given up and reassure that the DB is unaltered

# uncaught exception, DB likewise undamaged?

def process_spreadsheet():
    # open spreadsheet
    for row in spreadsheet_reader:
        try:
            with transaction.atomic()
                 process_row( row)
        except CannotStoreRow:
            # increment error count
            if too_many_errors():
                 raise CannotContinueLikeThis('Too many errors, giving up')

def process_row(row):
    #validate data in row, create and store multiple objects
    ...
    if ...:
        # explain the problem to the user
        raise CannotStoreRow  # abort this row, continue witht he next

    ...
    # and will this be OK, or does IntegrityError bork the outer transaction?
    try:
        object.save()
    except IntegrityError as e:
        # explain the problem to the user, then
        raise  CannotStoreRow  # to abort the row transaction but not the outer one
```